# Earth movers distance (EMD) between two multivariate normals. Is it negative definite distance?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, kernels, optimal-transportation

I was looking at the closed form formula for 2-Wassersteins distance for multivariate normal distribution on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Normal_distributions

It has a closed form given as follows:

$W_2(\mathcal{N}(m_1,C_1);\mathcal{N}(m_2,C_2))=\Vert m_1-m_2\Vert_2^2 +\mathrm{Tr}(C_1+C_2-2(C_1^{1/2}C_2C_1^{1/2})^{1/2})$

I could not find any references regarding positive definiteness or negative definiteness of the Wasserstein's distance between two normals. Is it an open question ?  I know that in general p-Wassersteins distances may not be negative definite (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64126/generalized-rbf-kernels). But here since we have a closed form it could be a special case. I will appreciate if someone can point out reference(s).

Comment: it is not nd in general i think; a quick expt shoud reveal that. on commuting matrices it is clearly an l2 distance

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 3):

The Wasserstein distance, defined and here for $p \geq 1$ for measures $\mu,\nu$ with finite $p^{th}$ moment as
$$
W_p(\mu,\nu) = \left( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \iint ||x-y||^p d\pi(x,y) \right)^{1/p}
$$
for $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of joint measures on $R^d \times R^d$ with marginals $\mu,\nu$,  is a positive definite distance; For any measures with finite $p^{th}$ moment (in particular true for Gaussians), one has 
$$
W_p(\mu,\nu) \geq 0, \quad W_p(\mu,\nu)= 0 \; iif\; \mu = \nu
$$
The proof can be found in Villani, topics in optimal transport, chapter 7.

## Concerning positive definiteness:

It is clear from the formula above and $\pi \geq 0$ (being a probability measure in the product space) that
$$
W_p(\mu,\nu) \geq 0
$$
It is also clear that if $\mu=\nu$, then $\pi(x,y)=\mu(x) \delta_{y=x}$ is optimal with transport cost $0$.

It remains to show that if $W_p(\mu,\nu)=0$ then $\mu=\nu$. This is because 
$$
W_p(\mu,\nu) = 0 \implies x=y \text{ on the support of } \pi \text{ (a.e.)}
$$
and hence one has necessarily $\pi(x,y)=\mu(x) \delta_{y=x}$ (one has always the disintegration $\pi(x,y) = \mu(x)\pi(y|x)$).

This implies that $\nu(y) = \int \mu(x)\delta_{y=x} = \mu(y)$.

## The Gaussian case

This implies in particular that for $m_1,m_2 \in R^d$ and $C_1, C_2$ positive definite matrices of $R^d$:
$$
||m_1-m_2||^2 + 2 Tr \left( \frac{C_1+C_2}{2} -(C_1^{1/2}C_2 C_1^{1/2})^{1/2} \right) \geq 0
$$
and $=0$ iff and only if $m_1=m_2$ and $C_1=C_2$.

This is true, regardless of any optimal transport consideration; the difficult term involving the trace of the covariance matrices is nonnegative thanks to an arithmetic/geometric mean (AGM) type of inequality (see [[1]](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379500000483/1-s2.0-S0024379500000483-main.pdf?_tid=6d9cd4ad-609f-4e54-8a7d-954a1877089c&acdnat=1527007924_026bd1e8f578e5dbbed12f5a6c39f787) for instance), and the equality case only works if we have equality of the matrices.

Comment: These are properties of metric spaces and it is true that p Wasserstein distance is a metric space. I think definition of positive definite / negative definite is different. I am looking into verifying that property. Look at Definition 2.21 for the definition of conditionally positive definite distance. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149889/prove-that-a-kernel-is-conditionally-positive-definite

Comment: I see, thanks for giving the definition. Say you have m Gaussians, and form the Gramm matrix using pairwise Wasserstein distances. Take an example where they have the same variance, and different means in a way that they are always separated by 1. For example, it is possible to find 3 Gaussians such that their Gramm matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This matrix is not cpd, as can be checked using the vector $c = (1, -1, 0)^T$. You can generalize it to $n$ Gaussians.

Comment: Thanks. But it may be conditionally negative definite and such distances have a characterization. I am trying to see if the case of Gaussian falls under that.Anyways it seems to be a hard question.